# Unknown compilation error in maven compile

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to compile my code using maven compiler plugin (3.7), but i am constantly getting unknown compilation error and during compilation system goes out of resources,Please have a look below for error logs. The Log doesn't help in locating the compilation issue, as the project is very big in size. It used to work fine earlier before we merged some feature to this branch, I checked pom.xml and there is no issue in dependencies and also project works fine in eclipse during development.

```
exec] INFO: Changing method name from isSubstitue to getSubstitue
 [exec] [INFO]
 [exec] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ siemops ---
 [exec] [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
 [exec] [INFO] Copying 26 resources
 [exec] [INFO]
 [exec] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ siemops ---
 [exec] [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
 [exec] [INFO] Compiling 1106 source files to C:\workspace\prj\target\classes
 [exec]
 [exec]
 [exec] The system is out of resources.
 [exec] Consult the following stack trace for details.
 [exec] java.lang.StackOverflowError
 [exec]     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitClassType(Types.java:4289)
 [exec]     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitClassType(Types.java:4275)
 [exec]     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:778)
 [exec]     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$UnaryVisitor.visit(Types.java:4532)
 [exec]     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitTypeVar(Types.java:4322)
 [exec]     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$UnaryVisitor.visit(Types.java:4532)
 [exec] [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
 [exec] [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
 [exec] [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
 [exec] [ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
 [exec] [INFO] 1 error
 [exec] [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I think this is a bug of java compiler, you should read : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240058/why-does-compiling-this-code-cause-a-compiler-stack-overflow, https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7116195, https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7123100

Answer (score 0):

try

```
MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -Xss1024k
```

Xss: should be set according to hardware available.

It'll increase heap memory.

Or

There may be recursive method call in your application, by which it is utilizing the whole heap memory. you need to avoid it

Comment: This question asks about compilation, recursive methods calls never fails compilation.